# PayPal PHP SDK - Set a tax in an invoice

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, invoice

I'm trying to insert a tax in this example https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/invoice/CreateInvoice.php using the setTax function and I always get an error. Could you help me?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the sample code for create invoice to include tax into each item. You can read more about the specifics on tax in [developer docs](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#create-an-invoice). As you can see, the tax field is present inside [invoice_item](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#invoiceitem-object). You can follow the sample code as shown below. To checkout the complete sample, visit [here](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/invoice/CreateInvoice.html).

```
// #### Tax Item
// You could provide Tax information to each item.
$tax = new \PayPal\Api\Tax();
$tax->setPercent(1)->setName("Local Tax on Sutures");
$items[0]->setTax($tax);
```

Now, if you run the [samples](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Samples) in your local machine, and run [SendInvoice](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/#invoice), you would see the tax included in the response.

[image]

The invoice would look something like this:

[image]